# Difference Sharing a link on Facebook using API Calls (Graphs API) or Share Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share), we know we can share a link on Facebook by using two method. The first one is using [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkshare) and the second one using [API Calls](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkapi) (Graph API).

I'm just confused, what difference using share dialog or API calls? and when we used?

Many thanks.

Ps. 
I think using API Calls(Graph API) is more complicated than we use Share Dialog. Using Share Dialog is more easier. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got my own answer :

## Share Dialog

The Share dialog is the newest way for people to share stories from apps. It lets apps share rich Open Graph stories and has full support for the Facebook post model, including giving people the ability to tag friends and places. The Share dialog is fully native and provides people the best experience of any of the sharing options. Share dialog can be used by anyone who uses your app, regardless of whether they use Facebook Login to connect an app to their Facebook account.

**Advantages**

100% native for a great, fast share experience

Support for sharing Open Graph stories

Does not require Facebook Login

**Disadvantages**

Needs the Facebook for Android app installed in the device. Apps that use the Share dialog may choose to fall back to the Feed dialog on devices when the Facebook app is not installed

## Graph API

The Graph API is the most powerful and flexible way for apps to share stories to Facebook. People must use Facebook Login to connect the app to their Facebook account, and then the app must request publish_actions permission. This gives the app permission to use the Graph API to post stories on behalf of people using the app. With Graph API access, apps can employ a tailor-made sharing experience and have the ability to tag friends and places and set the audience for a post.

**Advantages**

Lets apps build fully custom sharing experiences

Supports sharing Open Graph stories

## Best practices

For the best sharing experience, apps should use the share dialog by default and fall back to the web-based feed dialog if the Facebook app is not installed on the device.